# Is it possible to consider the left and right limit of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Would it be possible to consider such function eg. $\frac{z}{|z|^\frac{1}{2}}$ using left and right limits as z -> 0+ and z -> 0- since there is a square root sign involed

Or, would it be more "natural" to consider by letting the real and imaginary axis goes to 0. I'm partially stucked as to how to evaluate the complex function above!

Here's my attempt:

$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{|z|^\frac{1}{2}}$

For z = x + iy,

let x = 0, y -> 0: $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{|z|^\frac{1}{2}}$ = $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y}{(y^2)^\frac{1}{4}}$ = 0

let x -> 0 0, y = 0: $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{|z|^\frac{1}{2}}$ = $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{(x^2)^\frac{1}{4}}$ = 0

Seems weird as my gut feeling tells me that the limit wouldnt exist haha.

Comment: In complex analysis there are no such things as $z \to 0+$ or $z \to 0-$, convergency in a circle is considered. Maybe you need $z \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: thanks for the comment! but i would require z to be complex valued :)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. We can consider this as a limit in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and use polar coordinates. Let $z := x + iy$. Then $$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{\sqrt{\left|z\right|}} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\left(x,y\right)}{\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}} = \lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{r\left(\cos \varphi ,\sin\varphi\right)}{\sqrt{r}} = \lim_{r \to 0^+}\sqrt{r}\left(\cos \varphi, \sin\varphi\right) = (0,0)$$ Since the limit is independent of $\varphi$, we have $$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{\sqrt{\left|z\right|}} = 0$$

**Remark.** We can do this, since $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$. For example see Krantz's definition of the complex numbers. We could also just let $r \to 0^+$ for $z = re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: thanks for the comment! but since |z| has a square root to it, can we simply just ignore the "negative" part and only consider the positive part? :)

Comment: Which negative part? Negative real part? You are working on $\mathbb{C}$, where no order exists.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Author is considering two branches of the root.  But it doesn't matter here as the result is 0

Comment: Hi guys! thanks for the help! yeah, was quite confused because I thought I would have to consider the 2 roots say.. $\sqrt(-4)$ = 2i or -2i? oops.

Comment: @Bread it depends :) I recommend you to read about multivalued functions - it's a sophisticated field of complex analysis

Comment: @TheGeekGreek you've lost $i$ in your notes

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov That was dumb. I added now vector notation. Sorry. Adding $i$ would also be possible since it means basically the same.